# Mounting vmtoolsd to a docker container

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I'm running a docker container inside VM. Both are Ubuntu.

Is there a way to mount VM's `vmtoolsd` to the container and access it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your `Dockerfile` to install `open-vm-tools` which is almost the same like the official vmtools.

```
ENV OVT_VERSION 10.0.5-3227872
RUN mkdir -p /vmtoolsd/open-vm-tools \
    && curl -L http://downloads.sourceforge.net/open-vm-tools/open-vm-tools-$OVT_VERSION.tar.gz \
        | tar -xzC /vmtoolsd/open-vm-tools --strip-components 1
```